# Reduce dimension of numpy array by defined function

Tags: python, numpy, function

With a self defined function:

```
    def myfunc(x1,x2, ... ,x10):                 # list
        ... 
        matrix operation on x1, x2 ..., x10      
        ...
        return X                                 # one value
```

What is the right way to use array operation to transfer A to B by calling myfunc() like this:

```
    A.myfunc() >> B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import copy
def myfunc(x1,x2, ... ,x10):                 # list
    ... 
    matrix operation on copy.deepcopy(x1), copy.deepcopy(x2) ..., copy.deepcopy(x10)      
    ...
    return X      

B = myfunc(a,b,c,d...)
```

I think ... is what you are looking for

arrays are mutable so in your matrix operation you are likely modifying the original arrays... it sounds like you just want to return a new dataset without modifying the existing x1..x10 arrays

of coarse there is probably a 75% chance I didnt understand what you were asking ...

Comment: oops! I missed something important: A is a 4-dimensional array, B is a 3-dimensional array. I could use myfunc() with 3 loops to generate B from A. But I wonder whether there is a method to reduce the dimension of A from 4 to 3 by calling myfunc()

Comment: post A and B ... but small size example ... I dont understand what your input is nor your expected output

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response! Just make it simpler: A is 3 dimension (5*5*10), B is 2 dimension (5*5), myfunc() is a multiple linear regression function which returns a single value from 10 input values. So for each A[i,j,:] could generate a B[i,j] by calling myfunc() using iterative method: for i in range(5): / for j in range(5): / B[i,j] = myfunc(A[i,j,:]). But is it possible to call myfunc() in matrix without loops?

Comment: For example: A = np.random.randn(5,5,10), C = A.sum(axis = 2) would return a 5*5 array, how to do a similar way to let B = A.myfunc(axis=2)